# How can I show only a desired section and hide all others with vanilla Java Script?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm doing a landing page that builds the navigation menu dynamically with JS, and each item in the menu links with one section of the page.

Initially, all sections are hidden (CSS display: none), and then when the user clicks the menu item, the respective section appears.

The problem is that when I've already clicked on the menu to go to a certain section and then I click to go to another, both sections appear, and what I want is to only the section that I click appear, and the others hide.

For example, I click on section 2 then it appears. And when I click on section 4, section 2 disappears and section 4 appears.

This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Landing page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Antic+Slab&family=Henny+Penny&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="grid__container">
        <header class="page__header">
            <nav class="navbar__menu">
                <!--Mobile menu - won't appear on Desktop view-->
                <div class="mobile__menu" onclick="toggleMenu(this)">
                    <div class="bar1"></div>
                    <div class="bar2"></div>
                    <div class="bar3"></div>
                </div>
                <ul id="navbar__list" class="menu__list"></ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div class="banner__hero">
            <h1 class="heading__page">Landing Page </h1>
            <div class="banner__center">
                <ul class="motives__list__banner">
                    <li class="motives__item">Great motive</li>
                    <li class="motives__item">Great motive</li>
                    <li class="motives__item">Great motive</li>
                    <li class="motives__item">Great motive</li>
                </ul>
                <!--This review will only appear here on Desktop view-->
                <q class="quote__review"><b>Great review from one of your customers</b><br><br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi fermentum metus faucibus lectus pharetra dapibus.
                </q>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="page__button">Buy here!</button>
            <p class="introduction__text">Why someone would buy your product? (up to 5 lines)</p>
            <button type="button" class="page__button" id=buttonContent>More info here!</button>
        </div>

        <!--The sections will only appear when the appropriate button is clicked-->

        <main class="page__main">
            <section id="section1" data-nav="More motives" class="your-active-class section__box">
                <h2 class=" heading__section">More motives</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi fermentum metus faucibus lectus pharetra dapibus. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean aliquam elementum mi, ac euismod augue.</p>
                <p>Nunc molestie leo non cursus volutpat. Nam aliquam volutpat finibus. Cras rhoncus nec nisl sit amet pretium. Nullam scelerisque neque urna. Nam eget volutpat augue, eget lobortis enim.</p>
            </section>

            <section id="section2" data-nav="Images" class="section__box section__2">
                <h2 class="heading__section">Images/ Screenshots of your product</h2>
                <img src="img/product.jpg" alt="Product" class="product__image">
                <p>Morbi porttitor auctor enim, sit amet sagittis odio suscipit eu. Vestibulum rutrum mollis dolor, non tristique lacus luctus ac. Integer in ipsum eget nisl pellentesque imperdiet ac vel sapien. Mi dui, sagittis in erat id, rutrum efficitur nisi. Fusce varius risus enim, vitae accumsan eros tincidunt sit amet. Phasellus blandit finibus eros eu suscipit. 
                </p>
            </section>

            <section id="section3" data-nav="Reviews" class="section__box section__3">
                <h2 class="heading__section">Good reviews of your product</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi fermentum metus faucibus lectus pharetra dapibus. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean aliquam elementum mi, ac euismod augue. Donec eget lacinia ex. Phasellus imperdiet porta orci eget mollis. Sed convallis sollicitudin mauris ac tincidunt.</p>
                <p>Morbi porttitor auctor enim, sit amet sagittis odio suscipit eu. Vestibulum rutrum mollis dolor,non tristique lacus luctus ac. Integer in ipsum eget nisl pellentesque imperdiet ac vel sapien.</p>
                <p>Nunc molestie leo non cursus volutpat. Nam aliquam volutpat finibus. Cras rhoncus nec nisl sit amet pretium. Nullam scelerisque neque urna. Nam eget volutpat augue, eget lobortis enim. Proin hendrerit eu risus sed tempus. Nunc non lacinia sem, nec suscipit arcu.</p>
            </section>

            <section id="section4" data-nav="Maybe later" class="section__box section__4">
                <h2 class="heading__section">Maybe later?</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi fermentum metus faucibus lectus pharetra dapibus. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean aliquam elementum mi, ac euismod augue.</p>
                <p>Morbi porttitor auctor enim, sit amet sagittis odio suscipit eu. Vestibulum rutrum mollis dolor,non tristique lacus luctus ac. Integer in ipsum eget nisl pellentesque imperdiet ac vel sapien.</p>
                <p>Nunc molestie leo non cursus volutpat. Nam aliquam volutpat finibus. Cras rhoncus nec nisl sit amet pretium. Nullam scelerisque neque urna. Nam eget volutpat augue, eget lobortis enim.</p>
                <button type="button" class="page__button">Let's keep
                    talking</button>
            </section>

        </main>

        <footer class="page__footer">
            <h1 class="heading__section">Add me!</h1>
            <p class="contact-text"><a href="https://github.com/Bmg1612" class="contact">Github</a></p>
            <p class="contact-text"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/bruno-gurgel/" class="contact">Linkedin</a></p>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

This is my CSS:

```
/*
============================
Universal layout
============================
*/
body {
  max-width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Antic Slab", serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #1f2932;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffefba, #ffffff);
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

p {
  text-align: justify;
}

.grid__container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: min-content;
  grid-template-areas:
    "nav"
    "banner"
    "main"
    "footer";
  max-width: 100%;
}

.page__header {
  grid-area: nav;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu__list {
  font-family: "Henny Penny", cursive;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.menu__link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: 2px inset #000000;
}

.banner__hero {
  text-align: center;
  grid-area: banner;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted #000000;
}

.motives__item {
  list-style-image: url(../img/tick-mark.svg);
  font-weight: bold;
}

.heading__page {
  font-family: "Henny Penny", cursive;
  font-size: 4rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.page__button {
  border: 2px inset #000000;
  padding: 12px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
  background-color: #ffff00;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.page__button:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #9acd32;
}

.introduction__text {
  text-align: center;
}

.page__main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: justify;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 0 10px 0 5px;
  gap: 5px;
  height: 100%;
}

.heading__section {
  font-family: "Henny Penny", cursive;
  text-align: center;
}

.product__image {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

/* Setting the display to none, will change onclick with JS */
.your-active-class,
.section__2,
.section__3,
/* 
    The review will only appear in this part if the user is on a desktop.
    Otherwise, it will appear, in the section of reviews (3).  
    */
.quote__review {
  display: none;
}

.section__4 {
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
}

.page__footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  border-top: 2px dotted #000000;
}

.contact {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.contact-text {
  text-align: center;
}

/*
============================
Mobile layout
============================
*/
@media screen and (max-width: 599px) {
  .mobile__menu {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  /* Creating the sandwich menu */
  .bar1,
  .bar2,
  .bar3 {
    width: 2rem;
    height: 0.3rem;
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 6px 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
  }

  .menu__list {
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
  }

  .menu__link {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 12px;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border-bottom: 2px inset #000000;
    width: 50%;
  }

  .motives__list__banner {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 40%;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
  }

  .motives__item::marker {
    font-size: 4rem;
  }

  .introduction__text {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }

  .product__image {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

/*
============================ 
Tablet layout 
============================
*/
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 900px) {
  .mobile__menu {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  /* Creating the sandwich menu */
  .bar1,
  .bar2,
  .bar3 {
    width: 2rem;
    height: 0.3rem;
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 6px 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
  }

  .menu__list {
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
  }

  .menu__link {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 12px;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border-bottom: 2px inset #000000;
    width: 50%;
  }

  .motives__list__banner {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 20%;
  }

  .motives__item {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
  }

  .motives__item::marker {
    font-size: 4rem;
  }

  .page__button {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
  }

  .product__image {
    width: 80%;
  }
}

/*
============================
Desktop layout
============================
*/
@media screen and (min-width: 901px) {
  .mobile__menu,
  .change .bar1,
  .change .bar2,
  .change .bar3 {
    display: none;
  }

  .menu__list {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    font-family: "Henny Penny", cursive;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #ffefba;
  }

  .menu__link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom: 2px inset #000000;
  }

  .menu__link:hover {
    background-color: #657482;
  }

  .banner__center {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }

  .motives__list__banner {
    text-align: left;
    width: 20%;
    margin-left: auto;
  }

  .motives__item {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }

  .motives__item::marker {
    font-size: 4rem;
  }

  .quote__review {
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-style: italic;
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .introduction__text {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }

  .product__image {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

And this is my JS:

```
// Global variables
const sections = document.getElementsByTagName("section");
const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
const navBar = document.querySelector("#navbar__list");
const button = document.querySelector("#buttonContent");

// Function that creates dynamically the NavBar
function createNavBar () {
    for (section of sections) {
        const newElement = document.createElement('li');
        newElement.innerHTML = `<a class="menu__link" id="menu__${section.id}" href="#${section.id}"> ${section.dataset.nav}</a>`;
        fragment.appendChild(newElement);
    }
        navBar.appendChild(fragment);
        
}
    
// Calling the function    
createNavBar();

// Showing the sections content only when the linked Nav button is clicked
const menuLink = document.querySelectorAll(".menu__link");
const navList = document.querySelector('.navbar__menu');

navList.addEventListener('click', function showContent (event) {
    let currentSelection = event.target.id;
    let sectionNumber = currentSelection.slice(-1);
    let element = document.querySelector('#section'+sectionNumber);
    element.style.display = "block";
    })   

// Function to display the menu list on Mobile & Tablet layouts    
// Toggle between showing and hiding the navigation menu links when the user clicks on the hamburger menu / bar icon
function toggleMenu() {
    if (navBar.style.display === "block") {
        navBar.style.display = "none";
    } else {navBar.style.display = "block"}
} 

// If the button 'More info here' is clicked, all the content appears.
button.addEventListener ('click', function () {
    for (section of sections) {
        section.style.display = 'block';
    }
})
```

Comment: You simply need to loop through each element and toggle their individual visibility on each click.

Comment: Very possible. In your click handler, iterate over all sections and hide them, then set the clicked one to visible again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did it with the help of @Randy Casburn and @Chris G in the comments:

```
const sections = document.getElementsByTagName("section");
function showSection () {
    navList.addEventListener('click', function showContent (event) {
        for (section of sections) {
            section.style.display = "none";
            let currentSelection = event.target.id;
            let sectionNumber = currentSelection.slice(-1);
            let element = document.querySelector('#section'+sectionNumber);
            element.style.display = "block";
        }  
    })
}    
showSection();
```